# SQL 1785 Error: Workaround for ON UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables:

- **Countries**

  - PK: CountryId
- **Companies**: 1 country to many companies

  - PK: CompanyId
  - *FK*: CountryId
- **Users**: 1 country (not related to the country from a company) to many users

  - PK: UserId
  - *FK*: CountryId
- **CompanyUsers**: many companies to many users

  - PK, *FK*: CompanyId
  - PK, *FK*: UserId

I **cannot create one of the foreign keys with the ON UPDATE option** in the CompanyUsers table due to the mentioned error (cycles or multiple cascade paths etc.).

I understand the problem and I get that Microsoft recommends:

> To work around this problem, do not create a foreign key that will create more than one path to a table in a list of cascading referential actions.
>
> You can enforce referential integrity in several ways. Declarative Referential Integrity (DRI) is the most basic way, but it is also the least flexible way. If you need more flexibility, but you still want a high degree of integrity, you can use triggers instead.

But I would like to have synced foreign keys and the triggers are not working in this case.
How else can I approach this issue?

My attempt with triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [MyAttempt]
ON Users
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE t1
SET t1.UserId = t3.UserId
FROM CompanyUsers AS t1
INNER JOIN DELETED AS t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId

-- not correct, but here's the issue I don't know how to link what's old with what's new
LEFT JOIN INSERTED AS t3 on t2.UserId = t3.UserId
WHERE t3.UserId IS NULL 

END
GO
```

Comment: Why aren't triggers working for you?

Comment: Because I don't know how to use the DELETED and INSERTED tables to deduct which is the updated key and cascade the update to the children.

Comment: Can you show the trigger code you attempted?  Because that is how I would try to solve this.

Comment: Added my attempt. @TabAlleman yes, Users table.

Comment: Which table would you put this trigger on?   You cut out that part of the code.   Users?

Comment: What are your primary keys in `Users` and `Companies`? One of the key decisions (for me anyway) in identifying a candidate for a primary key is that it will **NEVER** change. If I can't find a satisfactory key, then I use a surrogate key, that way I don't need to deal with updating primary keys, which are nigh on impossible to handle in triggers because you have no link between the memory-resident `inserted` and `deleted` tables. Then you only need to handle deletes, which is fairly easy using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

Comment: @GarethD My thoughts exactly on update. For delete I don't care, I don't need to cascade it, that's the case where I want manual deletion of the entire "family" of rows.

Comment: Why does `UserID` ever change? Unless this is a one off update you have a serious design flaw. If it is a one off, then just disable the foreign keys while you do it. if it isn't a one off then I honestly think the most robust solution is to not have `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and simply rethink the process that updates the primary key.

Comment: Well you are correct, theoretically it shouldn't change, but I would really like the schema to be solid in terms of data integrity. I'm mostly concerned for data transfers (as in db place migration) where the keys get messed up or for human mistakes.

Comment: It will be solid, foreign key referential integrity won't allow the update. This will stop the human mistakes, and stop the keys getting messed up. I do not agree with the following one bit, but you could create a procedure that takes old and new id as a parameter and then: **1.** Disables the foreign key **2.** Updates the child table **3.** Updates the parent table **4.** Enables the foreign key, and do all this in a single transaction so if any part fails you can roll the whole thing back. But again, I really think you should just have no referential action, and just let the update fail.

Comment: @GarethD Yes, the procedure is overkill. As for the rest, you are right, thank you. Do you mind turning your comments into an answer (which I'll gladly accept) so that other paranoid people like me would see better what you told me?